# I have a problem , recordid null in my controller aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I need help with my lightin component the controller pass a null value of recordid, so i do not know whta can do, I tried everything. This is my code

### Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" controller= "oppstable" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
   
    <aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="opportunity"/>
    
    

   This is recordID {!v.recordId}
  
    
    
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler name="dataTableSaveEvent" event="c:dataTableSaveEvent" action="{!c.saveTableRecords}"/>    
    
    
    
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.data.length > 0}">
        <lightning:card title="Data Table">
            <c:dataTable aura:id="datatableId" auraId="datatableId" columns="{!v.columns}" data="{!v.data}" showRowNumberColumn="true"/>
        </lightning:card>
    </aura:if>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading.." variant="brand"/>
    </aura:if>
        


</aura:component>
```

### Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isLoading", true);
        helper.setupTable(component);
         var action = component.get("c.getRecords");
        var rec = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({accID : rec});
       
           $A.enqueueAction(action);        

            },
    
    
    saveTableRecords : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordsData = event.getParam("recordsString");
        var tableAuraId = event.getParam("tableAuraId");
        var action = component.get("c.updateRecords");
        action.setParams({
            jsonString: recordsData
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var datatable = component.find(tableAuraId);
            datatable.finishSaving("SUCCESS");
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);        
    },
    
})
```

### Helper

```
({
    setupTable : function(component) {     
       var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");  
        
        action.setParams({
            objectAPIName: "Opportunity",
            fieldAPIName: "Type"
            
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                var types = [];
                Object.entries(response.getReturnValue()).forEach(([key, value]) => types.push({label:key,value:value}));
                var cols = [
                    {label: "Account Name", fieldName: "accountLink", type:"link", sortable: true, resizable:true, 
                     attributes:{label:{fieldName:"Name"}, title:"Click to View(New Window)", target:"_blank"}},
                    
                    {label: "Type", fieldName: "Type", editable: true, type:"picklist", selectOptions:types},            
                               
                    
                ];
                component.set("v.columns", cols);
                this.loadRecords(component);
            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
                var message = "Error: Unknown error";
                if(errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0)
                    message = "Error: "+errors[0].message;
                component.set("v.error", message);
                console.log("Error: "+message);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
                    
    loadRecords : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRecords");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
                var allRecords = response.getReturnValue();
                allRecords.forEach(rec => {
                    rec.accountLink = '/'+rec.Id;
                });
                component.set("v.data", allRecords);
                component.set("v.isLoading", false);
            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
                var message = "Error: Unknown error";
                if(errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0)
                    message = "Error: "+errors[0].message;
                component.set("v.error", message);
                console.log("Error: "+message);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
                    
                    
})
```

### apex class

```
public with sharing class oppstable {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<opportunity> getRecords(String accID) {
        
        List<opportunity> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, Type, AccountId
                              FROM opportunity Where AccountId =:accID ORDER BY Name LIMIT 10];
        return accs;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateRecords(String jsonString){
        try{
            List<opportunity> records = (List<opportunity>) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<opportunity>.class);
            update records;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled        
    public static Map<String,String> getPicklistValues(String objectAPIName, String fieldAPIName){
        Map<String,String> pickListValuesMap = new Map<String,String>();
        Schema.SObjectType convertToObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectAPIName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult descResult = convertToObj.getDescribe();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = descResult.fields.getMap().get(fieldAPIName).getDescribe();
        Boolean isFieldNotRequired = fieldResult.isNillable();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
            if(isFieldNotRequired)
                pickListValuesMap.put('--None--', '');
            if(pickListVal.isActive())
                pickListValuesMap.put(pickListVal.getLabel(), pickListVal.getValue());
        }
        return pickListValuesMap;
    }
}
```

### Datatable component

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="auraId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortDirection" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <!--
        COLUMNS SHOULD BE IN BELOW FORMAT
        [{label: "Account Name", fieldName: "accountLink", type:"link", sortable: true, resizable:true, 
          attributes:{label:{fieldName:"Name"}, title:"Click to View(New Window)", target:"_blank"}},
         {label: "Created Date", fieldName: "CreatedDate", type:"date", editable: true},
         {label: "Active", fieldName: "Active__c", editable: true, type:"picklist", selectOptions:[{label:'Yes',value:'Yes'},{label:'No',value:'No'},]},
         {label: "Type", fieldName: "Type", editable: true, type:"picklist", selectOptions:types},            
         {label: "Shipping Street", fieldName: "ShippingStreet", sortable: true, },
         {label: "Shipping City", fieldName: "ShippingCity", editable: true},            
         {label: "Shipping State", fieldName: "ShippingState"},
         {label: "Shipping PostalCode", fieldName: "ShippingPostalCode"},
         {label: "Shipping Country", fieldName: "ShippingCountry"}], 
    -->
    <!-- LOCAL VARIABLES -->
    <aura:attribute name="dataCache" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="tableData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="tableDataOriginal" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="updatedTableData" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="modifiedRecords" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isEditModeOn" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="startOffset" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="buttonClicked" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="buttonsDisabled" type="Boolean" />

    
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="dataTableSaveEvent" type="c:dataTableSaveEvent"/> <!-- EDITABLE TABLE SAVE COMP EVENT -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="dataTableRowActionEvent" type="c:dataTableRowActionEvent"/> <!-- ROW ACTION COMP EVENT -->
    
    <aura:method name="finishSaving" action="{!c.finishSaving}" description="Update table and clode edit mode">
        <aura:attribute name="result" type="String" />
        <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
        <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default=""/>
    </aura:method>
    
    <div class="slds-table_edit_container slds-is-relative">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
            <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" />
        </aura:if>
        <table aria-multiselectable="true" class="cTable slds-table slds-no-cell-focus slds-table_bordered slds-table_edit slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_resizable-cols" role="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showRowNumberColumn}">
                        <th scope="col" style="width:50px;max-width:60px;text-align:center;">#</th>
                    </aura:if>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.columns}" var="col">
                        <th name="{!col.sortBy}" aria-label="{!col.label}" aria-sort="none" class="{!col.thClassName}" scope="col" style="{!col.style}">
                            <span class="{!!col.sortable ? 'slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_x-small' : 'slds-hide'}" title="{!col.label}">{!col.label}</span>
                            <a class="{!col.sortable ? 'slds-th__action slds-text-link_reset' : 'slds-hide'}" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" tabindex="0" onclick="{!c.sortTable}">
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Sort by: {!col.label}</span>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-has-flexi-truncate" title="{!'Sorty by: '+col.label}">
                                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!col.label}">{!col.label}</span>
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-arrowdown">
                                        <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.sortDirection=='asc'?'utility:arrowup':'utility:arrowdown'}" size="xx-small" 
                                                        class="{!v.sortBy==col.sortBy? 'slds-m-left_x-small':'slds-is-sortable__icon'}" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="{!col.resizable ? 'slds-resizable' : 'slds-hide' }" onmousedown="{!c.calculateWidth}">
                                <input type="range" min="50" max="1000" class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" tabindex="-1"/>
                                <span class="slds-resizable__handle" ondrag="{!c.setNewWidth}" style="will-change: transform;">
                                    <span class=""></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.tableData}" var="row" indexVar="rowIndex">
                    <tr aria-selected="false" class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showRowNumberColumn}">
                            <td scope="col" style="width:50px;max-width:60px;text-align:center;">{!rowIndex+1}</td>
                        </aura:if>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!row.fields}" var="field" indexVar="fieldIndex">
                            <td class="{!field.tdClassName}" role="gridcell">
                                <span class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!field.mode == 'view'}">
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!field.type == 'link'}">
                                            <a class="slds-truncate" id="{!rowIndex+'-'+fieldIndex}" href="{!field.value}" title="{!field.title}" target="{!field.target}">{!field.label}</a>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!field.type == 'link-action'}">
                                            <a class="slds-truncate" id="{!rowIndex+'-'+fieldIndex+'-'+field.actionName}" title="{!field.title}" onclick="{!c.onRowAction}">{!field.label}</a>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!field.type == 'date'}">
                                            <lightning:formattedDateTime class="slds-truncate" value="{!field.value}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" timeZone="UTC"/>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!field.type == 'number'}">
                                            <lightning:formattedNumber class="slds-truncate" value="{!field.value}" style="{!field.formatter}" currencyCode="{!field.currencyCode}" 
                                                                       minimumFractionDigits="{!field.minimumFractionDigits}" maximumFractionDigits="{!field.maximumFractionDigits}"/>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!!field.isViewSpecialType}">
                                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!field.value}">{!field.value}</span>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:if isTrue="{!field.editable}">
                                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:edit" variant="bare" name="{!rowIndex+'-'+fieldIndex}" onclick="{!c.editField}" alternativeText="{! 'Edit: '+field.value}" class="slds-cell-edit__button slds-m-left_x-small" iconClass="slds-button__icon_hint slds-button__icon_edit"/>
                                        </aura:if>
                                        <aura:set attribute="else"> <!--EDIT MODE-->
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!field.isEditSpecialType}">
                                                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.type == 'picklist'}">
                                                    <lightning:select label="Hidden" variant="label-hidden" class="slds-truncate ctInput" name="{!rowIndex+'-'+fieldIndex}" value="{!field.value}" onchange="{!c.onInputChange}">
                                                        <aura:iteration items="{!field.selectOptions}" var="pl">
                                                            <option value="{!pl.value}">{!pl.label}</option>
                                                        </aura:iteration>
                                                    </lightning:select>
                                                </aura:if>
                                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                                    <lightning:input name="{!rowIndex+'-'+fieldIndex}" type="{!field.type}" value="{!field.value}" variant="label-hidden" onchange="{!c.onInputChange}" class="ctInput"
                                                                     formatter="{!field.formatter}"/>
                                                </aura:set>
                                            </aura:if>
                                        </aura:set>
                                    </aura:if>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.tableData.length == 0}">
            <div class="slds-p-left_x-small slds-p-vertical_xx-small slds-border_bottom">
                No records found to display!
            </div>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isEditModeOn}">
            <div class="ctFooter slds-modal__footer">
                <div class="slds-text-color_error slds-p-bottom_small" style="{!v.error?'display:block':'display:none'}">{!v.error}</div>
                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
                    <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeEditMode}" />
                    <lightning:button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.saveRecords}" />                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>        
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please try to fix your code formatting so your post is readable and you can get help faster.

Comment: I think I fixed it, Thanks!!

Comment: Is your component added to a record page?

Comment: Yes, of cuorse, Actually when i added the component in the account record page, the only data that display is the ID cause  this line:<b>This is recordID {!v.recordId}</b>